# Visual Basic Web Browser change form when certain webpage content detected

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a form on VB.NET that when a certain webpage is loaded into the web browser (in this case its a .txt file with a string of numbers). It will look for those numbers and if it finds them it will close that form and open another. I have tried to do it many times and my latest attempts came out with this code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
       Dim passcontents As String
    passcontents = WebBrowser.DocumentText = "test.com/test.txt"

    If WebBrowser.DocumentText = "test.com/test.txt" And passcontents Then
        ActualGen.Show()
        Me.Close()
    Else

    End If
```

Comment: So you are trying to use a webbrowsercontrol in a windows-application? Are you trying to navigate to test.com/test.txt?

Comment: Yhea, its the wenbrowsercontrol and test.com/test.txt isnt the actual link im using, but i am still trying to read the text on an online text file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of basic problems with the code you've posted.

1)  Are you trying to test `passcontents` as a boolean or a string?  You've defined it as a String, but then you are trying to assign the equality of two other strings to it, as you would a Boolean.
Try setting `Option Strict On` at the top of your code - it gives a few more helpful pointers to check in this case.

2)  The `If... Then` condition is checking the same data as `passcontents` (may) already be providing.  Are you just trying to check that the correct page is loaded, or do you want to check for certain page contents as well?
You appear to be getting mixed up between the browser's document URL and the loaded document contents.

Comment: I am trying to get it so that it will detect certain contents on the page then it can progress on with the application. (onto another form)